# PHP crashes on preg_replace

Tags: php, crash, preg-match

I ran the following script using `php.exe`:

```
preg_replace('#(?:^[^\pL]*)|(?:[^\pL]*$)#u','',$string);
```

or its equivalent:

```
preg_replace('#(?:^[^\pL]*|[^\pL]*$)#u','',$string);
```

If `$string="S"` or `$string="  ذذ  "`  it works, if  `string='ذ'` it yields `�` that is incorrect , and if `string='ذذ'` PHP crashes.

But it works in 4.4.0 - 4.4.9, 5.0.5 - 5.1.6 versions.

What is wrong ?

**See**: http://3v4l.org/T3rpV

---

```
<?php
$string='دد';
echo preg_replace('#(?:^[^\pL]*)|(?:[^\pL]*$)#u','',$string);
```

> Output for 5.4.0 - 5.5.0alpha6
>
> ```
> Process exited with code 139.
> ```
>
> Output for 5.2.0 - 5.3.22, 5.5.0beta1
>
> Output for 4.4.0 - 4.4.9, 5.0.5 - 5.1.6
>
> ```
> دد
> ```
>
> Output for 4.3.11, 5.0.0 - 5.0.4
>
> ```
> Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N, \P, \p, \U, \u, or \X at offset 7 in /in/T3rpV on line 3
> ```
>
> Output for 4.3.0 - 4.3.10
>
> ```
> Warning: Compilation failed: PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N, \P, \p, \U, \u, or \X at offset 7 in /in/T3rpV on line 3
> ```

Comment: It crashes here, too. PHP 5.4.7.

Comment: I can confirm that it also crashes with the latest beta version **PHP 5.5.0beta2** (released 28th of March)!

Comment: @ComFreek Does my answer make it crash too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lastly, the bug was solved:

> ```
> Output for 4.4.0 - 4.4.9, 5.0.5 - 5.1.6, 5.5.27 - 5.5.33, 5.6.11 - 7.0.4, hhvm-3.6.1 - 3.12.0
>     دد
> ```

Answer (score 5):

You can use alternative mb_ereg_replace() function:

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
mb_regex_encoding("UTF-8");
echo mb_ereg_replace('#(?:^[^\pL]*)|(?:[^\pL]*$)#u','',$string);
```

Comment: no, its not you can [see it](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-replace.php)

Comment: Your regex  acts totally differently and is not equivalent to mine. Try: `$string='.d.'`

Comment: The RegEx should be reformatted to POSIX syntax. Also I am not sure that it POSIX support `\pL`

Answer (score 3):

maybe this will help :

> these properties are usualy only available if PCRE is compiled with
>   "--enable-unicode-properties"

http://docs.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php#96479

Comment: If those properties aren't available, PHP would emit warnings instead of crashing.

Comment: From my own experience, i`ve had a hard time when \b ( any word boundary character ) silently did not work with cyrillic symbols, it just ignored them, on the other hand, working as intended with latin. I had to use monster stuff like

`$boundL = '(^|[-\s\.><,:;\!\?]+)';`

`$boundR = '($|[-\s\.><,:;\!\?]+)';`

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the expression itself, there are two things that could be improved:

1. The `*` multipliers aren't very useful; why would you want to replace a potentially empty match with an empty string? In fact, running this on my system yields `NULL` from the `preg_replace()` operation.
2. The memory groups can be merged together.

This is the code after applying both improvements:

```
$string = 'ﺫﺫ';
var_dump(preg_replace('#(?:^[^\pL]+|[^\pL]+$)#u', '', $string));
// string(4) "ﺫﺫ"
```

[**3v4l results**](http://3v4l.org/lF95R)

If you're just looking for a multibyte trim function (supported from 4.3.0 onwards):

```
$string=' دد';
var_dump(preg_replace('#(?:^\s+|\s+$)#u', '', $string));
```

[**3v4l results**](http://3v4l.org/ZBXoX)

Comment: "In fact, running this on my system yields NULL" Wow! Actually you found anther bug: http://3v4l.org/H1Ihk

Comment: @PHPst Looks like it :) Does the code in my answer help though?

Comment: @Jack It doesn't crash but it outputs `string(6) "ﺫﺫ"` instead of your expected result.

Comment: @ComFreek the length in bytes doesn't say much though, not sure why both characters would take 3 bytes each.

Comment: @Phpst I understand. I would report a bug at bugs.php.net and refer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_quote` and you have to properly escape the special character before using it with your regex. For example:

```
<?php
$string = preg_quote("\دد");
echo preg_replace('#(?:^[^\pL]*)|(?:[^\pL]*$)#u','',$string);
```

See it in action: http://3v4l.org/LeBXg

More about [preg_quote](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php).

Cheers,

Ardy

Comment: `preg_quote` Quote regular expression characters and is not necessary for normal characters. Bur even `echo preg_replace('#(?:^[^\pL]*|[^\pL]*$)#u','',preg_quote('ذذ'));`  crashs. `preg_quote("\دد");` is `\\ss` that is a different string.

Comment: Perhaps you've misunderstood the purpose of `preg_quote()`, it's meant to escape special characters for use *inside* regular expressions :)

Comment: Don't mention it; the least I could do for a former colleague hehe.

Comment: @Jack Please refer to php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php and reread the question. Thanks.